# Swiching tabs programally in TabLayout

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I'm new to android programming and I can't find a way to switch between tab1 to tab2 in a TabLayout, when the user clicks a button located in the tab1.
It may be something very simple, but I am clueless in my first app.
I have tried the following at first:

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
tab.select();
```

And it used to work, but I changed the code and, at some point, it just didn't work anymore.
I also tried`tab.getCustomView().setSelected(true);`, but I got NullPointerException. So I checked in a if statement if *tab* was null, and it wasn't.
And then I tried

```
tabLayout.setScrollPosition(1,0f,true);
ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(mainView.getContext());
viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

But none of the solutions above worked for me.
Here is my code:

```
View view;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button GoB = view.findViewById(R.id.GoB);
        final EditText USETV = view.findViewById(R.id.USETV);
        final EditText commandEV = view.findViewById(R.id.CommandTV);
        final SqlHelper db = new SqlHelper(getContext(), "myDatabase", null, 1);
        GoB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    String a = "";
                    if (USETV.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                        a += "USE " + USETV.getText().toString() + " ;";
                    }
                    a += commandEV.getText().toString();
                    String[][] c = db.SqlQuery(a);
                    LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
                    View resultView = factory.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, null);
                    TableLayout tableLayout = resultView.findViewById(R.id.ResultContainer);
                    tableLayout.removeAllViews();
                    View mainView = factory.inflate(R.layout.main_activity,null);
                    TabLayout tabLayout = mainView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                    if (c[0].length > 0 && c[1].length > 0) {
                        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
                        //tab.select();
                        //tab.getCustomView().setSelected(true);
                        //tabLayout.setScrollPosition(1,0f,true);
                        //ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(mainView.getContext());
                        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        //
                        // do some stuff
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    showException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showException(e);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TabLayout` and `ViewPager` belong to your `Activity`, so in your `Fragment` you have to call `Activity` function to switch tab

Here is an example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public onCreate(...) {
        MyFrament myFragment = new MyFragment(this);
        // Add fragment to Viewpager ...
        // Attach ViewPager to TabLayout ...
    }

    public void switchTab(int index) {
        // Check index ...
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(index);
    }
}
```

then

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private Context mContext;
    private Button mButton;

    public MyFragment(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        ...

        mButton.setOnClickListener(v->{
            ((MyActivity)mContext).switchTab(1);
        });

        ...
    }
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks a lot. But **mContext** was not visible. So I used getContext() and it was all set.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting these two lines inside your button's handler :

```
ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar)getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);
```

Comment: I didn't get the chance to test your solution because I saw in the android documentation that **ActionBar** is in android.support.v7 and I'm looking for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click on your package name
2. new > activity > tabActivity click ok
3. Chose layout name whatever you want e.g (Example.java).
4. Select Navigation style is Action Bar Tabs(which is option 2) and click Finish

5.create two new Fragments

6.Go to the java file here Example.java

7. After open Example.java file paste the blow code in

SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter

public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {

```
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.

        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

        switch(position){


            case 0:

                return new Chats();

            case 1:

                return new Status();

            case 2:

                return new Call();
        }

        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {

        // Show 3 total pages.

        return 3;
    }
}
```